# ZeroDivisionError: float division error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I'm working on my python script for xbmc media application so I can update the text label with the percent string. I have set the label text with "0%" for the start, but I have no idea how to update the label text with "1%", "10%", "20%" and so on.

When I try this:

```
progressStartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = datetime.datetime.now() - progressStartTime
secondsLeft = int(delta.seconds) / float(percentageComplete) * (100.0 - 
percentageComplete)

if secondsLeft > 30:
  secondsLeft -= secondsLeft % 10
  self.setControlLabel(self.main_loading_time_left, "" % secondsLeft)
```

I'm having trouble with update the text in the label where I'm getting an 
error. The error I'm getting is: ZeroDivisionError: float division

The error are jumping on this line:

```
secondsLeft = int(delta.seconds) / float(percentageComplete) * (100.0 
- percentageComplete)
```

Can you please help me how I can update the text in the label with the percent string?

**Edit: Here is the update code:**

```
percentageComplete = 0

if percentageComplete < 1:
   self.getControl(4202).setLabel("1%")


progressStartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = datetime.datetime.now() - progressStartTime
secondsLeft = int(delta.seconds) * (100.0 - percentageComplete)

if percentageComplete > 1:
   secondsLeft -= secondsLeft % 10
   self.getControl(4202).setLabel(secondsLeft + "%")
   #self.setControlLabel(self.main_loading_time_left, "%" % secondsLeft)
```

Comment: I assume percentageComplete starts with 0.

Comment: it is already set to 0 when I use `percentageComplete = 0`. Any idea?

Comment: You are dividing by 0 because percentageComplete is 0...

Comment: Oh I see so can you please tell me what change I would need to make even if I don't need to dividing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine what time is left when you're at 0%. Exclude that case with a if case.

Comment: can you tell me how I can update the text in the label when I have the string in label text with `1%`?

Comment: When you're not at 0%, this thing is correct. What do you mean by "how can I update" ? Can you show us the context of the call ?

Comment: When I have the text "1%" in the label, the code supposed to be update the new text from `1%` to something is like `10%`, `20%` or whatever it is. On my code, the text in the label are still show `1%`. Please see the update code in my first post.

Comment: When I try the code I use `self.getControl(4202).setLabel(secondsLeft + "%")`, I will get an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: str(secondsLeft) should do the trick for this.

Are you looping on this function ? Because right now, your data will only be updated once. Plus, I'm not sure this will update correctly. Do you know what is the end time, assuming you have the beginning time (i.e. : do you know how long you media lasts ?)

Comment: Yeah I'm looping on this function when I have the text `1%` in the label which I'm trying to get over it to replace with the new text to something is like `10%`, `20%` or whatever it is when I'm running the code. I have no idea how you mean how long the media lasts?

Comment: If you can compute the actual percentage of completion, doing this
`self.getControl(4202).setLabel(str(PercentageCompletion)+"%")` should do the trick. I don't know how you can get the PercentageCompletion. But if you can answer that, you're good :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, so when I try this: `percentageComplete = 0

if percentageComplete < 1:
   self.getControl(4202).setLabel("1%")

secondsLeft = 20 * (100 - 10) / 100
secondsLeft -= secondsLeft % 10
self.getControl(4202).setLabel(str(secondsLeft)+"%")`


It will set the text "1%" in the label and it will replace it with "10%", but it have stop updating. Do you have any idea why it have stop updating?

Comment: How many time do you call your `setLabel` function ? You look like you're calling it only once ? If `secondsLeft` represent your completion percentage, check that it's value changes over time. If it's always equels to 10, this will always set your label to `10%`

Comment: Yes I'm calling it once so it should continue to update the text in the label from `10%` to `100%`, but it only stay `10%` in the label. Can you help?

Comment: setLabel only set the value once. It can't be updated again if you don't call it again. You have to loop over it to change this value. Maybe try `while secondsLeft > 1` instead of `if`.

Comment: Yeah I can see that setLabel can only set the value once. So when I use the `while secondsLeft > 1`, how i can get the setLabel to be updating in each time I count the number of 10, 20, 30, 40 and so on until I get 100? any idea how i can do that?

Comment: Try to compute your label value from `secondsLeft` (it's probably not exactly equals to secondsLeft, because you're at 100% when secondsLeft is equal to 0 I guess). Then, in the while loop, decrease the value of `secondsLeft`. I'm don't know after that. Try things and see how you can make it work better

Comment: do I need to set the secondsLeft value at 0? and how i can decrease the value of secondsLeft in the while loop? if you could post the code it would be much easier for me to understand what I can do to try to achieve.